# Docker - Modificar php.ini

Tags: php, laravel, docker, composer, docker-compose

tengo un archivo dockerfile para mi proyecto laravel donde monto un contenedor para mysql y otro para apache, de esta manera

```
FROM php:7.4.1-apache

USER root

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        zip \
        curl \
        unzip \
        vim \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-source delete

COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && a2enmod rewrite
```

Estos contenedores los tengo funcionando, el problema lo tengo al intentar instalar un paquete mediante composer de php que me da error de memoria, para ello he probado a editar los archivos  **php.ini-development y  php.ini-production** de la carpeta :/usr/local/etc/php# , pero sin éxito, el error que obtengo es este.

```
root@xxxxxxx:/var/www/html# composer require tcg/voyager
Using version ^1.4 for tcg/voyager
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted 
(tried to allocate 655360 bytes) in 
phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Decisions.php on line 19
```

Una pregunta relacionada, como puedo reiniciar apache? con apache2 -k restart me da error.

Comment: Igual deberías mostrar la parte relevante del `php.ini-development` y `php.ini-production`.

Comment: ¿Cuánta RAM tiene asignado el POD o la máquina virtual donde ejecutas este contenedor? Por defecto no hay límite de uso de memoria por parte de PHP cuando se ejecuta en símbolo del sistema, pero si agotas la RAM entonces te saldrá el error.

Answer (score 1):

Es un error común con proyectos de alto consumo de recursos. Hay varias formas de hacerlo. Siguiendo la lógica de que usas un Dockerfile para levantar tu proyecto, simplemente necesitas agregar esta línea a tu Dockerfile

```
RUN cd /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ && \
  echo 'memory_limit = -1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ram-limit.ini
```

Puede ser **-1** o el límite que desees siempre siguiendo la nomenclatura 128**M** (para megabytes) o 1**G** (para gigabytes)

Cuando levante tu contenedor, solo debes acceder al mismo y ejecutar:

```
php -i | grep "memory_limit"
```

Y esto debería mostrate el total de memoria asignado para tu proyecto.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Deberías llevar memory_limit en php.ini al menos a 1700m.

Además podrías correr phpinfo() que te indicará la ruta de php.ini y así confirmar que estás modificando el php.ini correcto.

Answer (score -1):

prueba:

```
cp php.ini-production php.ini

/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```